# Spring session scoped bean gives exception

Tags: spring-mvc, session, spring-boot

I have a user session bean

```
 @Component 
 @Scope(value="session", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
  public class Session implements Serializable{
    private String name;
    private String token;

  // public setter and getters
  }
```

And I inject it from singleton controller

```
@Controller
public class LoginControllerImpl implements LoginController {

@Inject
Session session;    

@Override
    public ResponseEntity< ? > sessionControl(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

        if(session.getTckn()== null){
            return new ResponseEntity<>(session, HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
            //throw new Exception("Session is invalidated");
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(session, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

}
```

After this i have this exception;

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No serializer found for class org.springframework.context.expression.StandardBeanExpressionResolver and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: com.project.helper.Session$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1ca3b63d["targetSource"]->org.springframework.aop.target.SimpleBeanTargetSource["beanFactory"]->org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory["beanExpressionResolver"])
```

And always  go to my login page like an infinit loop.

When i delete @Scope(value="session", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
it goes perfecly to main page.

How can i resolve this? Thanks for your help.